# How to find out which X11 driver system is using?

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, x11, graphics

How to find out which X11 driver system is using?

For my chip `openchrome` is the best driver but I suspect that system is not using it. I just need at least 2D acceleration.

How can I check?

Here is it what I found from `cat /var/log/Xorg.7.log | grep driver`:

```
[    54.147]    X.Org XInput driver : 12.3
[    55.167] (==) Matched openchrome as autoconfigured driver 0
[    55.167] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 1
[    55.167] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2
[    55.167] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    55.175] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/openchrome_drv.so
[    55.499] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    55.570] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    55.649] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    55.649] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    55.652] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/openchrome_drv.so
[    55.652] (!!) VIA Technologies does not support this driver in any way.
[    55.984] (II) CHROME(0): Not using driver mode "1280x1024" (height too large for virtual size)
[    55.986] (II) CHROME(0): Not using driver mode "1280x1024" (height too large for virtual size)
[    58.049] (II) AIGLX: Trying DRI driver /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
[    61.982]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 12.3
[    61.982] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[    62.014] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[    62.084] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Logitech USB Optical Mouse'
[    62.093] (II) No input driver/identifier specified (ignoring)
[    62.103] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'NOVATEK USB Keyboard'
[    62.119] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'NOVATEK USB Keyboard'
```

From what I have got it's not using `openchrome`.

Here's `lspci | grep VGA`:

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VX800/VX820 Chrome 9 HC3 Integrated Graphics (rev 11)
```

(This is a Thin Client.)

And this is output of `grep -E '(\(WW|\(EE)' /var/log/Xorg.7.log`:

```
             (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    34.285] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    34.286] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    34.286] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    34.286] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1" does not exist.
[    34.286] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    34.286] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    34.287] (WW) The directory "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType" does not exist.
[    34.308] (WW) Open ACPI failed (/var/run/acpid.socket) (No such file or directory)
[    34.817] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[    34.817] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    34.854] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[    34.911] (EE) CHROME(0): Unknown Card-Ids (1122|A0A0| 702), Chipset: VX800/VX820; please report to openchrome-users@openchrome.org
[    37.878] (EE) [drm] drmOpen failed.
[    37.878] (EE) CHROME(0): [dri] DRIScreenInit failed.  Disabling DRI.
[    38.065] (WW) CHROME(0): [XvMC] XvMC is not supported on this chipset.
```

Form `xvinfo | head -10`

```
X-Video Extension version 2.2
screen #0
  Adaptor #: "XV_SWOV"
     number of ports: 1
     port base: 62
     operations supported: PutImage
     supported visuals:
       depth 24, visualID 0x21
     number of attributes: 6
       "XV_COLORKEY" (range 0 to 16777215)
```

Comment: Does `lsmod | grep openchrome` show anything?

Comment: Kevin, showing nothing!

Comment: Based on the output it is using `openchrome` driver but cannot set the 1280x1024 mode

Comment: isn't it using DRI instead of openchrome?

Comment: @casey_miller DRI is an extension which may or may not be supported by the driver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your original question, yes you are using the OpenChrome driver.  It just unfortunately has minimal support for your chipset, even less if it isn't the most recent.
As of now you should be able to get Basic 2D, and whatever 2D acceleration was supported for your chipset.  Its up to you to say if its 'good enough', or worth changing to something better.

Openchrome has gone through a lot of improvement from after 09`, and distro's always end up many releases outdated. Chrome 9 support has improved in recent OpenChrome releases, which should provide better performance/stability/features.

In addition a proprietary driver exists for Chrome 9 HC3, but not every distro has a package available. This is the better option for an outdated distro.  Basically which way to go depends on your distro's release, and/or if you compiled yourself.

I might be able to direct you to a easy upgrade option, need distro version to know.  If you don't know it helps to Identify LSB Release

```
## outdated distro's might not support this command    
lsb_release -a

## Most Distro's will display release, in an /etc file.
cat /etc/*release
```

Check for Video Overlay

```
## Still verify Xv works, whenever you get X running again.
## xvinfo | head -10
```

Comment: I have included the output of the last two commands. I couldn't run glxinfo (doesn't exist, figuring out how to install) and xvinfo (I do have it but getting: xvinfo: Unable to open display) (I don't have window manager)

Comment: @casey_miller: I updated my answer to reflect your question.  The ball is now in your court.  Accept answer when you know its good enough, or I could always help you upgrade.

Comment: the fun thing is that it can play HD video full screen with current hardware and driver (btw the version is Package: xserver-xorg-video-openchrome (1:0.2.904+svn920-1) I am running 11.10. In packages list of 12.04 version the version of openchrome is the same

Comment: that version is fairly recent, you don't need to change if it's working. Your distro is too recent to get benefits from the closed driver, so your best off staying where you are.

Comment: The problem hasn't gone but I think this answer can be accepted. And for further actions I can create other questions. Thanks!

Comment: I was able to run xvinfo finally! you can look at it in the updated question

Comment: Your `xvinfo` output is correct, which is why your video was running well.  Xv is the video overlay, which is not as fast when lacking XvMC.  Although just regular Xv is considerably faster than without, and my card won't support XvMC either... So i go plain Xv.

Comment: Also remember to disable all extraneous graphic effects, if you have any installed.  The real objective is making sure compositing is disabled, and that depends on which WM you have installed.  You can run all the modern desktops with Openbox as the window manager, and I use it also.  It runs light and doesn't do built in Compositing.  I actually do Openbox alone, but I've done it with both Gnome and KDE, in the past.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which system you are on the location of the X log may be different but on Linux: `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.  If you search for the word `driver` you will be able to see lines like this:

```
[    34.252] (==) Matched fglrx as autoconfigured driver 0
[    34.252] (==) Matched ati as autoconfigured driver 1
[    34.252] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 2
[    34.252] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
```

This means that it will use one of these drivers for it.

You can also take a look at:

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

search for the `Device` section which will tell you which driver it will use.  You can also try doing:

```
sudo X -configure
```

to create the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`

Based on your further comments you should look at [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenChrome) for more guidance.  You may have to play with options like for 10.04 release to see if you can get it to work.

Comment: Here is what I got from /var/log/Xorg.7.log (it's 7 not 0 for some reason). See updated question.

Comment: @Karlson How can you tell he's using Ubuntu?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek In the comments in the answer below OP mentions running version 11.10 and 12.04.  11.10 is the latest Ubuntu release and 12.04 is currently being tested.  And Ubuntu's versioning scheme is pretty unique.